# Return the current month as text in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'd like to return the current month as text, e.g "January". I have the following, which returns the month number:

`SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`

returns:
`1`

And the following which returns the month name based on the number:

`SELECT to_char(to_timestamp (1::text, 'MM'), 'Month');`

returns
`January`

But I can't find a way of combing them into one line, that returns the current month as "January".

Thank you

Comment: `SELECT to_char(to_timestamp ((SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))::text, 'MM'), 'Month');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'Month')
```

Yields:

```
January
```